# Produce multiples of a value in function of tokens ( MS excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, token, cell

I would like to produce multiples of value in function of the amount of tokens available from another cell.
I have a constant value ‘pippo’ if the amount of tokens is 2 then there should be pippo twice in another cell (pippo;pippo).

Pratically, I would like the third column to be as shown below:

```
Value   Token_Count Value_Token
Pippo   3           pippo;pippo;pippo
        2           pippo;pippo
        5           pippo;pippo;pippo;pippo;pippo
        1           pippo
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a data setup that matches your description, use this formula in cell C2 and copy down:

```
=MID(REPT(";"&$A$2,B2),2,B2*(LEN($A$2)+1))
```

[image]

Comment: @CallumDA What if the Token_Count is 255?  Then the length of the string will be much longer than 255 and the result would be incorrect.  I know that's probably an unlikely edge case, but I believe it's better to be accurate with a longer formula, than potentially inaccurate with a shorter one.

Comment: My bad.. I think I'm getting confused (possibly with VBA). I thought the limit for strings in a cell was 255 chars.

Comment: @CallumDA That was true for Excel 2003 and below, but they upped the limit with Excel 2007 and higher where the maximum number of characters allowed in a cell is 32,767.  See [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EBABAAA=2007) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up - moment of madness on my part!

Comment: Posted another solution which is very similar to this one, if you want to update your answer I'll happily delete it :)

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,REPT($A$1 & "; ",B1))
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

This will also work:

```
=TEXTJOIN(,,REPT($A$1 & "; ",B1))
```

Comment: Nice solution for those with Excel 2016 :)

Comment: @CallumDA  *TEXTJOIN()* and *AGGREGATE()* were the only reasons I purchased Excel 356.

Comment: Haha, how is AGGREGATE different in 365? (I think it's been available since 2010?)

Comment: @CallumDA  My previous version was 2007

Comment: Wow... I didn't know the first thing about Excel in 2007 ;)

Comment: The first formula =MID(REPT(";"&$A$2,B2),2,B2*(LEN($A$2)+1)) function perfectly. I am still to adapt the other ones.                                                                                                       Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option

```
=$A$2&REPT(";"&$A$2,B2-1)
```

Comment: Clever, I like it :)

Comment: However, this needs a slight adjustment, or you'll get too many repetitions: `=$A$2&REPT(";"&$A$2,B2-1)`

Comment: @tigeravatar Good spot!